# Passing array into table

Tags: asp.net, arrays, vb.net

I'm creating multiple choice question system.
So far i create these 4 tables and 1 view.

The tables are tblQuestion, tblAnswer, tblQuiz, tblResult and tblResultDetail. 
tblQuestion is to store the questions, tblAnswer to store the answers of the question,tblResult is to record for every user that answers the quiz, and store the users answers in TblResultDetails.

Based on the code below, the data is read from view. (questiondr.Read). I use 1 , 2 , 3, 4 as it is the column name of the view. I did this to randomize the answers.

```
Dim MyArray(3) As String
    Dim commd As New SqlCommand("Select * From view_Question Where =QuestionID=@IdQuestion", conn)
    commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdQuestion", count)
    Dim questiondr As SqlDataReader
    questiondr = commd.ExecuteReader


If questiondr.Read() Then
    Me.lblTitle.Text = questiondr("txtQuestion")

    Me.ansrb1.Text = questiondr("1")
    MyArray(0) = questiondr("1")

    Me.ansrb2.Text = questiondr("2")
    MyArray(1) = questiondr("2")

    Me.ansrb3.Text = questiondr("3")
    MyArray(2) = questiondr("3")

    Me.ansrb4.Text = questiondr("4")
    MyArray(3) = questiondr("4")


    Dim userAns As String

    If Me.ansrb1.Checked = True Then
        userAns = MyArray(0)
    ElseIf Me.ansrb2.Checked = True Then
        answerId = MyArray(1)
    ElseIf Me.ansrb3.Checked = True Then
        userAns = MyArray(2)
    ElseIf Me.ansrb4.Checked = True Then
        userAns = MyArray(3)
    End If

End If
conn.Close()
```

End Sub

And the problem is, how to pass the users answers into table tblResultDetails?

Comment: Off-by-one, array needs 4 elements.

Comment: what do you mean by that? can you explain more?

Comment: `Dim MyArray(3) As String` this is an array that could contain only 3 strings (index from 0 to 2). You need `Dim MyArray(4) As String` to store 4 strings (index from 0 to 3). With only 3 elements, when your code tries to use the index 3 you will receive an Index Out Of Range exception at runtime. This situation is called `off-by-one` [See Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error)

Comment: `Dim MyArray(3) As String` gives me 4 elements(0 to 3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that `tblResultDetails` contains a field for the `userid`, a field for the `questionid` and a field for the answer given by that particular user to that particular question then you need something like this

```
Dim cmdText = "INSERT INTO tblResultDetails VALUES (@userid, @questionid, @answerid)"
Dim cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, connection)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", yourCurrentUserIDValue)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@questionid", yourCurrentQuestionIDValue)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@answerid", userAns)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

As you can see it is pretty straightforward if you have stored somewhere the two missing informations (userid and questionid)

Comment: i tried this code and there is error which is the input string was not in a correct format